# Call to undefined method App\Models\Unidades::__set_state()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error when i try to run artisan commands, like "php artisan config:clear" or "php artisan route:clear".

```
 BadMethodCallException 

 Call to undefined method App\Models\Unidades::__set_state()
```

But, in my "Unidades" model, it doens't have anything calling to this method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unidades extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'nome',
    'endereco', 
    'telefone',
    'coordenador',
    'diretor_tecnico',
    'responsavel_tecnico_da_enfermagem',
    'responsavel_tecnico_da_farmacia',
    'inicio',
    'termino',
    'imagem',
    'nome_abreviado',
    'arquivos'
];
}
```

Did anybody else faced this problem ? I've looked into other forums, but all of the solutions where to put "use HasFactory" in the model, but as you can see, it's already there.. I have no idea on how to solve this..

Comment: Do you use any package ? (3rd-party)

Comment: this is my composer.json:

"require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },

Comment: I'm using Livewire, but it didn't show any errors.. the one i'm facing now, came out of nowhere apparently (i didn't update nothing, didn't installed anything new)

Comment: Have you checked if the version of php cli is the correct one? Las time I saw that issue was caused by having a diferent php version in cli that the one in the web server, solved by calling the php with full route "/etc/php/....../php artisan config:clear".